# Anonymous class question

Tags: java, constructor, anonymous-class

I've a little doubt over this line:

> An anonymous class cannot define a constructor

then, why we can also define an Anonymous class with the following syntax:

```
new class-name ( [ argument-list ] ) { class-body }
```

Comment: Thanks to all! Now I understood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not defining a constructor in anonymous class, you are calling a constructor from superclass.

You can't add a proper constructor for anonymous class, however, you can do something similar. Namely an initialization block.

```
public class SuperClass {
   public SuperClass(String parameter) {
       // this is called when anonymous class is created
   }
}

// an anonymous class is created and instantiated here
new SuperClass(parameterForSuperClassConstructor) {
   {
      // this code is executed when object is initialized
      // and can be used to do many same things as a constructors
   }

   private void someMethod() {

   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your example creates an anonymous *subclass* of `class-name`, and you are not permitted to create a constructor specific to your anonymous class. The argument list you give is the same as the argument list for the `class-name` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This implies that an abstract class exist called `class-name` with the defined constructor. You are making use of that constructor in your anonymous class similar to using super() in the constructor of a sub class.