# Java initialization

Tags: java

I've been coming across this code several times and I would like to know what it means or what it is equivalent to:

```
A a = new A() {
  // declare some methods and whatever
};
```

What does the above mean? What is it equivalent to (if it is equivalent to anything)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're declaring an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).  Class `A` is (likely) either an interface or an abstract class that must have implemented methods in order to be a subclass of `A`.  Java allows you to define those methods on the fly with anonymous classes.

For example, there is only one method to implement for `ActionListener`, which is `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`.  Many times it's easier to define that method in an anonymous class like so:

```
ActionListener myListener = new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    // do other stuff for action performed
  }
}
```

***Edit in response to the OP's comment***

You could certainly create a class file for an `ActionListener` and create a new instance of your class instead of creating an anonymous class.  That is, assuming you could do everything you needed to do in a separate class.  Many times anonymous and inner classes are defined so that you can have access to the outer class's fields and methods.  It is also many times more object oriented to define an inner or anonymous class if the the inner class "belongs" to the outer class and to no one else.

Comment: it can also be a concrete class that you want to provide some additional functionality for or want to use the double brace initialization `new HashMap<String,String>(){{put("one","val1");put("two","val2");put("three","val3");}}`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Of course the overhead of using double brace initialization is generally not worth the concise syntax provided.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Plus the instances where it would be *truly* valuable (e.g. initalizing Collections), the compiler complains about version UUIDs.

Comment: @Tim Pote, why can't one just separate the anonymous class into another .java file and declare in there and use its instance in the original file? Wouldn't that be clearer?

Answer (score 4):

It's making an anonymous inner class: `a` is an instance not of `A` itself but of a newly made subclass of `A`, as if you'd written something like

```
public class MadeUpName extends A {
    ...
}
A a = new MadeUpName();
```

but without having to make up a `MadeUpName` and with less verbiage.

Answer (score 2):

It's an anonymous class.  While I've never used them extensively, they're convenient for cases where you'll only be using a class once, or don't want to 'pollute' your top level class hierarchy with something that won't be seeing much reuse.

You can place them in inside a class (with standard *public, private, protected* keywords) or within a class method (inner class).

I couldn't find a really nice, succinct write-up/tutorial, but this is OK:

[Anonymous classes from java in a nutshell](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Related:

- [Declaring Anonymous Inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511864/declaring-anonymous-inner-class)
- [Anonymous class question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758189/anonymous-class-question)
- [Anonymous class question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1758189/anonymous-class-question)

Answer (score 1):

This is instantiation of an anonymous class that extends / implements the class / interface A.